# Add weights to density function

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization, kernel-density

I want to create a chart where predicted values are on the X axis and actual values are on the Y axis, with a scatter plot of points that also has a density plot weighted by volume. The observations also have a "units" variable associated with them. I want to create a density plot or heat map of those points but want to use the volume variable to weight the points for purpose of creating the contours / colors. I have this code below, but when I run it I get a warning indicating that it didn't actually use the weights. It creates the exact chart I want, but doesn't use the weights to create the shapes.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#random data for purposes of post -- but in real world I have an actual dataframe here
X =  np.random.rand(100000)
Y =  np.random.rand(100000)
units =  np.random.rand(100000)

# Combine X, Y, and units into a DataFrame
kde_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': X,
    'Y': Y,
    'units': units
})

# Drop rows with NaN values
kde_data.dropna(inplace=True)

# Check if there is sufficient data
if len(kde_data) < 3:
    print("Insufficient data to create the density plot.")
else:
    # Create a KDE plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
    sns.kdeplot(data=kde_data[['X', 'Y']], weights=kde_data['units'], fill=True, cmap='viridis')
    plt.title('Density Plot with units as Weights')
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.show()
```

and get this warning along with the plot:

```
The following kwargs were not used by contour: 'weights', 'fill'
```

I would just duplicate the observations by a factor of the weight, but would run into serious compute resources shortages -- way too many observations and weights are in millions in some cases.

Comment: Seaborn prefers that you explicitly tell it what you want as `x` and `y`.  Can you try `sns.kdeplot(data=kde_data, x='X', y='Y', weights='units', fill=True, cmap='viridis')`?

Comment: In seaborn 0.13.2 (the current version), this code results in `ValueError: The following variable cannot be assigned with wide-form data: 'weights'`. As such, In addition to the solution provided by @JohanC, it's likely you will need to update seaborn. [Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O00k6.png). With conda `conda update --all`, otherwise with pip.

Comment: Mmm -- I updated seaborn and with the new syntax I get this error: TypeError: _bivariate_kdeplot() got multiple values for argument 'x'

Comment: You should update / edit the question with the exact code used for kdeplot

Comment: Yeah sorry my mistake -- it actually did work -- I just hadn't re-imported seaborn after updating. Thanks for the help!